# Logstash Forwarder

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

Trying to send some logs to logstash server. Using logstash forwarder to forward the logs to logstash

But its getting timed out:

```
2015/03/04 08:19:15.266955 Started harvester at end of file (current offset now 10659): /apps/azuga-dds/logs/amqData.log
2015/03/04 08:19:15.267089 Setting trusted CA from file: /etc/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.crt
2015/03/04 08:19:15.290016 Connecting to [10.90.9.242]:5000 (ec2-54-70-33-51.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com)
2015/03/04 08:19:20.290259 Failure connecting to 10.90.9.242: dial tcp 10.90.9.242:5000: i/o timeout
2015/03/04 08:19:21.291691 Connecting to [10.90.9.242]:5000 (ec2-54-70-33-51.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com)
2015/03/04 08:19:26.291903 Failure connecting to 10.90.9.242: dial tcp 10.90.9.242:5000: i/o timeout
2015/03/04 08:19:27.293218 Connecting to [10.90.9.242]:5000 (ec2-54-70-33-51.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com)
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you able to connect to 10.90.9.242:5000 with e.g. telnet? In other words, does this problem have anything to do with logstash-forwarder or is it a general network connectivity issue?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Magnus .. above was seems to be firewall issue fixed and it went fine ...

Comment: But now started facing something weird on Logstash :


log4j, [2015-03-10T16:17:46.469]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty:
 [logstash-ip-10-217-223-172-32621-4016] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x2
f519d64, 
/10.254.4.102:57123 :> /10.217.223.172:9301]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format

Comment: What version of Logstash and what version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: logstash=1.4.2-1-2c0f5a1
elasticsearch=1.1.1

Comment: Looks like now it throws below Exception on Logstash Forwarder :
2015/03/12 11:13:59.248852 Connecting to [10.217.223.172]:9301 (10.217.223.172)
2015/03/12 11:13:59.262326 Failed to tls handshake with 10.217.223.172 x509: certificate is valid for 10.90.9.242, not 10.217.223.172

Any suggestion to fix this ?? 
I have tried generating new certificate but no luck

Answer (score 2):

You may have some problems with SSL cert, sometimes checking cert may help. And be sure that you are using same version of JVM on logstash-forwarder, logstash and elasticsearch. Generate cert with your logstash-server IP, log says that you try to connect to host with IP, that not listed in cerificate.

Try

```
 openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host:port
```

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a new ssl cert in the logsatsh server (10.90.9.242) with the IP-SAN alternate name which means editing the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf and adding:
    `subjectAltName = IP:10.90.9.242`
under the [v3_ca] section.
and only afterwards generating the cert and key by running:
    `openssl req -x509 -batch -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout     /etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key -out    /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt -days 3650` 
Don't forget to reset the logstash and move the crt and key to the correct path of the logstash-forwarder (written in the config file).